# Web Api Help Page, multiple Get same parameter break help generator

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an OData Controller that exposes three different GET methods.

```
// http://odata/Companies
IQueryable<Company> Get()

// http://odata/Companies(1)
SingleResult<Company> Get([FromODataUri] key)

// http://odata/Companies(1)/Persons
IQueryable<Persons> GetPersons([FromODataUri] key)
```

Using this approach the OData Links convention works perfectly but the Help Generator creates only 1 method, the `Get()`, while it skips *`Get{key}`* and *`GetPersons{key}`*

If I change the methods in this way:

```
// http://odata/Companies
IQueryable<Company> Get()

// http://odata/Companies(1)
SingleResult<Company> Get([FromODataUri] key)

// http://odata/Companies(1)/Persons
IQueryable<Persons> GetPersons([FromODataUri] companyKey)
```

the help is generated but Web Api OData doesn't work anymore cause the framework is looking for a "key" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OData v4(System.Web.OData.dll instead of System.Web.Http.OData.dll), you can resolve this issue through attribute routing:

```
[ODataRoute("Companies({companyKey})/Persons")]
IQueryable<Persons> GetPersons([FromODataUri] companyKey)
```

For more info about attribute routing, you can reference https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataAttributeRoutingSample/.

Comment: I tried the following solutions

Companies({companyKey})/Persons

but when I call http://api/odata/Organization(1)/Persons the route is not found

if I call http://api/odata/Organization(1)/GetPersons I get a different error
No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.

Comment: What is your code for configures the request processing pipeline? httpConfigurations.MapODataServiceRoute(...)? if yes, delete the api/ and try odata/Organization(1)/Persons.

Comment: I had to create a custom EntityRoutingConvention because the version 4 of Web Api OData can't handle the routes properly if the parameter is different than "key"